# How to add more of these yellow handles for the line tool in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

How to add more of these textboxes that have handles that are attached to the line tool in Visio?

[image: screenshot]

Please see the picture, there is a yellow handle right in the middle.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new line, then double click that line. That will add text to the line and that text field will have a yellow "handle" that you can move it about with.

If you want text boxes then add text boxes.

If you want your text boxes to move with other objects then group them.

Comment: I meant on a single line, having 3 text boxes, and that yellow handle if you noticed is the text box's dongle, and grouping item doesn't make the same result as you notice you can't ungroup the line component when has a text on, so I don't know what that object is, I am trying to implement the same thing,
idk if I have to code that with VB.net, idk idk

Comment: I manage to add one more handle but without a textbox, check the image I added to the original post